# How to change a background image dynamically in styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, background, styled-components

I'm trying to change the background dynamically and it doesn't work. I have been seeing several posts that talk about this and none have helped me.

```
const image = '../../../public/pictures/background.jpeg';

<Card url={image} />

export const Card = styled.div`
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-image: ${props => `url('${props.url}')`};
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 225%;
`
```

Comment: Why are you using Card before it being declared? Try to move `<Card url={image} />` line below

Comment: Im using it in other component don't worry about it

Comment: Try checking the dev inspector in your browser. Select the element and see if the background image is being applied. It could be that it isn't sized correctly. Also depending on your build system, the image may not be imported correctly.